# Viewing output from Ruby in terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal

Sorry for the very basic question.

System information:

- Language - Ruby
- Texteditor - Sublime 2
- Shell - Terminal
- Operating System - Mac Mavericks

Problem: I am writing code in ruby. How do I view in terminal the results/output from the code? For example, When I run the following code I would like to see how the gsub and squeeze commands modify the test document?

For example:

```
       require 'tactful_tokenizer'
       require 'treat'           
       require 'pry'            
       require_relative 'lib/extensions/String'

       include Treat::Core::DSL         # Gives quick access to named entity 
       tt = TactfulTokenizer::Model.new # Creates an instance of the tokenizer


       keywordRegexes = [/death/,
                        /died/,
                        /passed \s+ away/xm,]


      #Open example documents

      Dir.glob('examples/*.txt'). each do |filename|
      testdocument = File.open(filename).read


      testdocument.gsub!(/[\n\r]/," ")  
      testdocument.squeeze!(" ")

      end
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using pry, you can insert "binding.pry" in the .rb file wherever you want for debugging and run your ruby file. This way you can run your script and dynamically check the values.

Example: I have inserted the binding.pry in the line #5. And debugging the code for some values.

RubyTest username$ ruby timetest.rb 
    "26/11/2014"

```
From: /Users/username/Languages/Ruby/RubyTest/timetest.rb @ line 5 :

     1: require 'pry'
     2: timenow = (Time.now.utc + 86400).strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
     3: puts timenow.to_s.inspect
     4: 
 =>  5: binding.pry
     6: 
     7: option="24/11/2014 - 30/11/2014"
     8: 
     9: puts option.include? timenow
    10: 

[1] pry(main)> timenow
=> "26/11/2014"
[2] pry(main)> timenow.include?"24/11/2014"
=> false
```

Answer (score 1):

After each method you could use the `puts` method to see the state of the `techdocument` variable:

```
  testdocument.gsub!(/[\n\r]/," ")  
  puts testdocument
  testdocument.squeeze!(" ")
  puts testdocument
```

Comment: More tersely you can use `tap`: `testdocument.gsub!(…).tap{ |x| p x }`. Guaranteed not to change the return value of your method, unlike an extra `puts` as the last statement.